# MySQL CONCAT script

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I want to ask if I have a table like below

```
Date & Hour               Phone           Status
2012-03-06 16:33:12     0292561234  Congestion
2012-03-06 16:33:12     0292561234  Congestion
2012-03-06 16:34:45     0292561234  Congestion
2012-03-06 16:46:50     0292561234  Congestion
2012-03-06 17:17:01     0292561234  Dial
2012-03-07 12:01:39     500         Queue
2012-03-07 12:02:10     500         Queue
2012-03-07 12:03:06     500         Queue
```

I need to join them like

```
Date & Hour               Phone           Status
2012-03-06 16       0292561234  Congestion,Congestion,Congestion
2012-03-06 17       0292561234  Dial
2012-03-07 12       500         Queue,Queue,Queue
```

So I'm using a CONCAT condition in

```
SELECT calldate, dst, GROUP_CONCAT( lastapp )
FROM cdr
GROUP BY hour( calldate ) ;
```

But it's showed like

```
Date & Hour               Phone           Status
2012-03-06 16:33:12     0292561234  Congestion,Congestion,Congestion,Dial  
2012-03-06 17:17:01     0292561234  Dial
2012-03-07 12:01:39     500         Queue,Queue,Queue
```

Am I using wrong script ?

Please be advised.

Thank you,

Comment: Other than the time format, your desired result looks like your output.

Comment: you're grouping by `hour(calldate)`, so you're getting exactly what you wanted. perhaps you mean `date(calldate)` so you group on `yyyy-mm-dd`, instead of just `hh`?

Comment: Are you sure there are no `Dial` in the 16th hour?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b1d1/1 - It doesn't match either your expected result or example result.  Is the problem with the `Status` list, or the `Date & Hour` having minute and seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT DATE(calldate), dst, GROUP_CONCAT(lastapp)
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY dst, DATE(calldate);
```

Refer http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/

Comment: How is this different from the OP's sample query?

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(calldate,1,13) as date_hour, dst, GROUP_CONCAT( lastapp )
FROM table
GROUP BY date_hour
```

Answer (score 0):

this will also work...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calldate,"%Y-%m-%d %h"), dst, GROUP_CONCAT( lastapp )
FROM cdr
GROUP BY hour( calldate ) ;
```